# SSRS 2008 R2 upgrade - webservice access issue - 401 unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, web-services, unauthorized

we have upgraded to SSRS 2008 R2 from a SSRS 2008 instance. This was an upgrade in-place and so the reports and datasources were brought over to the new instance.

from the application side (asp.net), we use the SSRS Webservice (ReportService2005.asmx) to makes calls such as ListChildren, GetPolicies to handle some application specific scenarios.

however, after the upgrade to R2, the web service call to ListChildren fails with a "401, unathorized" message.

```
ReportingService2005 reportService = new ReportingService2005();

                reportService.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerWebserviceUrl"];

                reportService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportViewerUser"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportViewerPassword"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportViewerDomain"]);
                reportService.PreAuthenticate = true;                

                SSRSReportServer.CatalogItem[] _reportItems = new SSRSReportServer.CatalogItem[] { };

_reportItems = reportService.ListChildren(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootFolder"], true);
```

the code in the asp.net app is as above. the account being used in the NetworkCredential above is active and i have checked to make sure that the account is not locked out.

the account is setup as Content Manager on the SSRS folder that the code is trying to access.

when i browse to http://server/reportserver/reportservice2005.asmx - i am able to see the wdsl for the webservice.

overall, this is working code, when pointed to a Sql2008 SSRS instance - and the 401 error shows up on the Sql2008 R2 instance.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is your web server set up to use delegation for your SQL2008 instance but not your R2 instance?   Since you set the credentials on the web server this may not be an issue, but it is a fairly common problem.